# How do we simplify $\cos^4\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\sin^4\alpha-\sin^6\alpha$ to $\cos^6\alpha$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do we simplify $$A=\cos^4\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\sin^4\alpha-\sin^6\alpha$$ to $$\cos^6\alpha?$$

I really have troubles simplifying that expression. I have tried everything that came into my mind:

$$A=(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)^2-3\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha-\sin^6\alpha=1-3\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha-\sin^6\alpha\\=1-\sin^2\alpha(3\cos^2\alpha-\sin^4\alpha)=?$$ $$A=\cos^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)+\sin^4\alpha(1-\sin^2\alpha)=\cos^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha+\sin^4\alpha)=?$$

Comment: Hint: add $\sin^6\alpha$ to both sides so the equation no longer hides the sine/cosine symmetry. The rest comes down to factorizing $x^3+y^3$ with $x:=\sin^2\alpha,\,y:=\cos^2\alpha$.

Comment: @J.G., but it's not an equation so we don't have 2 sides... I was supposed to simplify $A$. I didn't know the given answer until I checked in the book.

Comment: If you ask "how is $u=v$?", _that's an equation_.

Comment: @J.G., I hode the edit makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=& \cos^4\alpha-\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\sin^4\alpha-\sin^6\alpha\\
&=&\cos^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha+\sin^4\alpha)\\
&=&\cos^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha(1-\sin^2\alpha))\\
&=&\cos^4\alpha(1-\sin^2\alpha)\\
&=&\cos^6\alpha.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

You can try to be clever, but you can just chug along.

Let $\cos^2(\alpha)=x$. Then $\sin^2(\alpha)=1-x$. What you want to show is

$x^2-x(1-x)+(1-x)^2=(1-x)^3+x^3$.

Exxpand everything:
$3x^2-3x+1=3x^2-3x+1$

So it's true.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2&=\cos^4x+\sin^4x-2\cos^2x\sin^2x\\(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2&=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)(\cos^4x+\sin^4x-\cos^2x\sin^2x)-\cos^2x\sin^2x\\(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2&=\cos^6x+\sin^6x-\cos^2x\sin^2x\\\cos^4x+\sin^4x-2\cos^2x\sin^2x&=\cos^6x+\sin^6x-\cos^2x\sin^2x\\\cos^4x+\sin^4x-\cos^2x\sin^2x-\sin^6x&=\cos^6x\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

We could write everything in terms of powers of cosine (which is basically **Max**'s method) or in terms of powers of sine:

$$ \cos^4\alpha \ - \ \sin^2\alpha·\cos^2\alpha \ + \ \sin^4\alpha \ - \ \sin^6\alpha $$
$$ = \ \ (1 \ - \ \sin^2\alpha)^2 \ - \  \sin^2\alpha·(1 \ - \ \sin^2\alpha) \ + \ \sin^4\alpha \ - \ \sin^6\alpha $$

$$ = \ \ (1 \ - \ 2·\sin^2\alpha \ + \ \sin^4\alpha)  \ - \  \sin^2\alpha  \ + \ \sin^4\alpha  \ + \ \sin^4\alpha \ - \ \sin^6\alpha $$

$$ = \ \  1 \ - \ 3·\sin^2\alpha \ + \ 3·\sin^4\alpha   \  \ - \ \sin^6\alpha  $$
(which are the terms of a "binomial-cube", thus)

$$ = \ \  (1 \ - \  \sin^2\alpha )^3 \ \ = \ \ (\cos^2 \alpha)^3 \ \ = \ \  \cos^6 \alpha \ \ . $$